# Can the SOP expression be the same as POS expression?

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra

I have a function as F(A,B,C,D)=M0+M4+M12+M8
I'm getting the simplified Product of Sum expression as C+D
but I'm getting the same expression again as Sum of product

Comment: The only difference is that you write C+D (SOP) or (C+D) as (POS). Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Please don't use the sop tag without checking that it is appropriate (it isn't).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.